# How to refer a bean inside "util:list" bean?

Tags: java, spring

I have the bean definitions like below

```
<util:list id="myBeanList">
<bean id="stage1" class="Stageclass"/>
<bean id="stage2" class="Stageclass"/>
</util:list>
```

I know that If we want to refer the above list, we can use something like

```
<ref bean="myBeanList" />
```

But, I don't want to refer the whole list, instead i want to refer a particular bean inside this list, say "stage1". May be something like `<ref bean="myBeanList$stage1" />` ?

Is it possible to refer an inner bean like this? Is yes, how to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) to do this.

```
<ref bean="#{myBeanList[0]}" />
```

However, I'm not sure you'll be able to access by bean's id within the list. List will not allow you to access anything by bean id or name (that is inherently a Map kind of pattern). If you need by-name access, you should consider putting all your beans in a map and then expression language should allow you to access it by name. [Here is an example](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-expression-language-access-map.jsp) of how you can access elements from map by bean id.

One reference of expression language I found is [this](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-expression-language-access-list.jsp). Take a look at how studentList is used in the spring-config.xml.

Comment: Is this the part of core-springs or do we need to add any jar files in our maven pom.xml or import any spring related xmlns for this?

Comment: You need to add dependency on spring-expression in your pom.xml with the right version http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression

Comment: Referring by index might not work in my case since the list is not fixed. Please let me know if you find anyway to access the bean using name or id. I am upvoting the answer. Thanks for you effort.

Comment: Please try this `<util:map id="myBeanMap"><entry key="stage1"><bean class="Stageclass"/></entry><entry key="stage2"><bean class="Stageclass"/></entry></util:map>`  And access it using
`<ref bean="#{myBeanMap['stage1']}" />`